# How to create Amazon DocumentDB Elastic cluster via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I want to create managed MongoDb using DocumentDb on AWS via terraform.

I created a DocumentDb Elastic cluster via the UI, and it seems to work fine. Now I want to create this cluster via terraform, and I don't find documentation for it.

I read that only the documentDb's 'Elastic Cluster' support MongoDb Sharding APIs (and not the 'Instance Based Cluster').

[This](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/docdb_cluster) is the Hashicorp doc for DocumentDb, but I don't see reference for Elastic cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentDB is relatively new. I think it's not possible to do it on terraform yet.

You can do it using [Cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-docdbelastic-cluster.html)

Using [AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_docdbelastic/CfnCluster.html)

Or [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/elastic-get-started.html)

I think it will be available soon, if it is possible with other IaC Terraform don't take too long to update.

Comment: Support to elastic clusters has been added in 4.63.0. See [pull request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/30666).

Comment: Still not clear how to create an elastic cluster, though. terraform seems to create a Regional one every time.